Handling Calls and Chat Notifications When App is in Background or Terminated in flutter

on click of notification when app is terminated how to navigate on a particular calling screen in app
when app in background its working fine
I am developing a mobile app with calling and chatting features. I need the app to handle incoming calls and chat notifications when it is in the background or terminated.
Requirements:
Background Mode:
Handling incoming calls and chat notifications.
Terminated State:
Managing calls and messages when the app is closed.
Notifications and Services:
Setting up push notifications and background services for calls and chats.
Development Environment:
Platform: [Android, iOS, or both]
Framework: [Flutter, React Native]
Notification Service: [e.g., Firebase Cloud Messaging]
What I Have Tried:
Looked into background services and push notifications but need a comprehensive solution.
Questions:
How to handle incoming calls and chat notifications in the background or terminated state?
Best practices for these scenarios in Flutter and React Native?
Specific libraries or APIs for these tasks?
Configuration of push notifications for effective handling?
Any advice, examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
